# Microsoft.Bcl.Build What is it used for

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, dotnetopenauth

I just tried to download and build the `DotNetOpenAuth.Samples` from the [GitHub](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.Samples). But got a error from `nuget.targets` said `The process cannot access the file 'xxx\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll' because it is being used by another process`.

So I checked in the targets file. found `<RestoreCommand>$(NuGetCommand) install "$(PackagesConfig)" -source "$(PackageSources)" -o "$(PackagesDir)"</RestoreCommand>` caused the error.

In the `packages.config` I found the `<package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="net40" />` defined.

Since I found the project doesn't really reference the dll. So I just comment the package configuration. and rebuild it. The error is gone.

But my problem is why this package is not being referenced in the project while it is defined in the package configuration? What is it `(Microsoft.Bcl.Build)` used for?

Thanks.

**Updated**

Forgot to add the information from nuget.

> This package provides build infrastructure components so that projects
>   referencing specific Microsoft packages can successfully build.
>
> Do not directly reference this packages unless you receive a build
>   warning that instructs you to add a reference.

Still can not understand it well yet..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, it's a helper layer for NuGet packages. The [announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/08/22/improved-package-restore/) of Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0 provides the details:

> The new version of Microsoft.Bcl.Build will ensure that solutions
>   containing our packages will load successfully even if packages aren’t
>   restored yet. This affects all .NET NuGet packages that depend on it,
>   such as Microsoft.Net.Http, Microsoft.Bcl, and Microsoft.Bcl.Async.
>
> Microsoft.Bcl.Build will give an actionable error message in cases the
>   package was missing by asking you to build again.
>
> When coupled with NuGet 2.7 where package restore is automatic in
>   Visual Studio and isn’t implemented through MSBuild, the experience is
>   transparent and smooth. However, this doesn’t address build server
>   scenarios yet so you still need run nuget.exe restore solution.sln
>   prior to build, or check-in the .targets file if preferred.